# Intersection of two arrays by row

Tags: julia

I just switched to Julia from MATLAB and I am looking for a way to find the intersection of two arrays by row. For example, if C = [1 0;0 1], D = [-1 0;0 1] the output will be B, ind1, ind2 = [0 1], 2, 2.

A MATLAB counterpart would be: [B,ind1,ind2] = intersect(C,D,'rows')

How can I do this? Is there a built-in function in some module that would enable this operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define:

```
function intersectML(ms::Array...)
  t = map(x->Dict(x[2][i,:]=>(x[1],i) for i=1:size(x[2],1)),enumerate(ms))
  u = intersect(map(keys,t)...)
  return (u,map(x->[x[r][2] for r in u],t)...)
end
```

And then you have:

```
julia> C = [1 0;0 1]; D = [-1 0;0 1]

julia> intersectML(C,D)
(Array{Int64,1}[[0,1]],[2],[2])
```